# ListView not shown after setting custom listView adapter

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, listview, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to show a listView which should contain sender number and sms body. I am creating a custom adapter for this purpose.

Here is the class code in which i am creating and setting custom adapter(MapInbox.java).

```
View baseView;
ArrayList<String> sms_id = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> sms_num = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> sms_Name = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> sms_dt = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> sms_body = new ArrayList<>();
String smsBody, senderNumber;
ListView lvSms;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    baseView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map_inbox, container, false);
    lvSms = (ListView) baseView.findViewById(R.id.lv_sms);

    Uri myMessage = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
    ContentResolver cr = getActivity().getContentResolver();
    Cursor c = cr.query(myMessage, new String[]{"_id", "address", "date",
            "body", "read"}, "address = '03414503584'", null, null);
    getActivity().startManagingCursor(c);
    getSmsLogs(c);
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            CustomMessagesAdapter customMessagesAdapter = new CustomMessagesAdapter
                    (getActivity(), R.layout.listview_messages);
            lvSms.setAdapter(customMessagesAdapter);
        }
    }, 150);
    return baseView;
}

public void getSmsLogs(Cursor c) {

    if (sms_num.size() > 0) {
        sms_id.clear();
        sms_num.clear();
        sms_Name.clear();
        sms_body.clear();
        sms_dt.clear();
    }
    try {
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                if (c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")) == null) {
                    c.moveToNext();
                    continue;
                }
                senderNumber = c.getString(
                        c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address"));
                smsBody = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body"));
                Log.e("Body-->", "" + smsBody);
                Log.e("Number-->", "" + senderNumber);

                sms_num.add(senderNumber);
                sms_body.add(smsBody);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        c.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private class CustomMessagesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {


    CustomMessagesAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
        super(context, resource);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_messages, parent, false);
            viewHolder.tvSenderNumber = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_sender_number);
            viewHolder.tvMessage = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_message);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.tvSenderNumber.setText(senderNumber);
        viewHolder.tvMessage.setText(smsBody);
        return convertView;
    }

}

private static class ViewHolder {
    TextView tvSenderNumber;
    TextView tvMessage;
}
```

Code of MapInbox Layout file:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/messages_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_sms"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
</ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

And the custom listView layout code for messages(listview_messages.xml):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:background="@drawable/messages_background"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_sender_number"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_message"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

messages_background

```
    <solid android:color="#00000000" />
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#FFF" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="1dp"
        android:left="1dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:top="1dp" />

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="15dip"
        android:bottomRightRadius="15dip"
        android:topLeftRadius="15dip"
        android:topRightRadius="15dip" />
</shape>
```

I am getting all the required messages in logs and the reason why i have set the text color to white is because app's background is black.

What am i doing wrong here?
Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest that you organise your data in a single place first. You can make a Plain Old Java Class (namely, SMSData) containing all the SMS details and then Use this class to define the type parameter of ArrayList. Apart from this, you are not passing a data source to the adapter on which it can work.

Answer (score 0):

The ListView Adapter you are writing has no idea what the source of your data is at the moment..

```
@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_messages, parent, false);
        viewHolder.tvSenderNumber = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_sender_number);
        viewHolder.tvMessage = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_message);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    viewHolder.tvSenderNumber.setText(senderNumber);
    viewHolder.tvMessage.setText(smsBody);
    return convertView;
}
```

Adapters have a method called `getCount()` which you should override and provide it with on how many items it should show. This number you provide is used to feed the `int position` in the `getView()` method you overrode and implemented. Right now, the Adapter thinks you have no data funnelled to it (i.e. `getCount()` is returning 0) so it does not load anything. To solve this problem it's best you consolidate all the data you want to show into a custom class like Abhiroj Panwar has said above, add them into an ArrayList, then in your getView access each set of data using the `int position` given in the `getView()` method.

```
viewHolder.tvSenderNumber.setText(yourCustomArrayListClass.get(position).senderNumber);
viewHolder.tvMessage.setText(yourCustomArrayListClass.get(position).smsBody);
```